# Cannot extract names of subnodes under a node

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have a XML file like this:

```
<book>
    <chapter name="chap1">
        <section name="c1sec1">
            <paragraph name="title1">sample</paragraph>
        </section>
        <section name="c1sec2">
            <paragraph name="title2">sample1</paragraph>
        </section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter name="chap2">
        <section name="c2sec1">
            <paragraph name="title3">sample2</paragraph>
        </section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter name="chap3">
        <section name="c3sec1">
            <paragraph name="title4">sample3</paragraph>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

I want to extract the sections from specific chapters. Suppose from "chap1", the output should be like this:

```
c1sec1
c1sec2
```

I have written the following piece of code to achieve this:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("chapter");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node n = nodeList.item(i);
    NamedNodeMap m = n.getAttributes();
    if(m.getNamedItem("name").getTextContent() == "chap1")
    {
        System.out.println(n.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What output are you getting?  Is it empty?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem is using == to compare strings instead of equals

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the simpler `getAttribute()` method:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("chapter");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element el = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
    if (el.getAttribute("name").equals("chap1"))
    {
        System.out.println("Found chap1");
    }
}
```

You'll then need similar code to extract the section names from the chapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try `m.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue()` instead of `m.getNamedItem("name").getTextContent()`

Comment: This is the wrong solution, getNodeValue returns null for an element

Comment: Luckily, getAttributes returns a NamedNodeMap containing attributes and not elements.